# Is stock data available for bulk download for free?

Tags: finance, historical, time-series

Is it possible to download a dump of stock data?

I've seen the following:

- [Alternative to google finance api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10040954/562769)
- [Is there anywhere to get a free stockmark data feed/dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3535088/562769)
- [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/help/libraries) - seems only to offer current prices. The "bulk downloading" option

But I'm not interested in the current data, but rather a dump for the past years (at least one value per day) for the most important stocks (e.g. the ones in [DAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX), [Dow Jones Industrial Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average), ...), preferable with the price from Frankfurt or Xetra.

Is such data available for free?

(Non-free options are only interesting for me if it is below 20 Euro and if one may publish images created with this data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stock market historical data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4116/stock-market-historical-data)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting link :http://computeraidedfinance.com/2011/11/23/how-do-i-get-free-real-time-market-data-into-excel/
Inside you will find this : http://code.google.com/p/finansu/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on SE. It's best to remove this or elaborate what the resource offers and why it's pertinent.

Comment: Your post is better suited as a comment as it is written. One of the reasons not to simply link out is that it makes the value of the OD questions dependent on external factors outside of the OD community's control.