# Google Finance Error: Sorry, you may be sending automated queries

Tags: data-request, api, finance

Using javascript, I tried pointing to a JSON from google at this URL:

www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AAPL&callback=?

Then I got the error:

> Sorry, your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To
>   protect our users, we cannot process your request right now.

**Question:** Is that supposed to happen? I would like to circumvent this error. I'm thinking I may have misunderstood how "open" their api is. Do I still need an authentication key or something? Is that hard to do -- and more importantly is it still free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error in the browser, so I guess your URL is old. Google Finance isn't an API (the [API was shut down](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-finance-apis) in 2012, so in effect you are just scraping)... Checkout [Yahoo Finance or others](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4116/1511) for a more official unofficial API.

In the browser:

```
https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NSE:AAPL
```

does work but without the `&callback=?`

---

see this link for a workaround

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073520/2327328